# How to compile JeMalloc on Windows?

Tags: c++

How can I compile JeMalloc on Windows? I've looked on their github and there are no instructions how to build it.

Comment: hey, are you able to find exact instructions to install and configure on windows.. can you please share.. I am able to build but not install and configure

Comment: Since end of 2017 both VS2015 and VS2017 are supported i believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build it with MinGW - probably MinGW-w64.  Use MSYS2 to run the install scripts.  It basically mimics a Linux environment on Windows.  Follow the directions in the `INSTALL` file in the repository.  You should be able to Google the details.  Any decent MSYS2 build tutorial should be helpful.