# jemalloc env setup on Windows VS2017

Tags: c, jemalloc

I'm following the instructions given [here](https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc-cmake/tree/master/msvc) (this page indicates VS2015, but the folder obtained from released jemalloc contains sln for both 2015 and 2017), and it fails running:

```
bash -c "CC=cl.exe ./autogen.sh"
```

from "VS x86 Native Tools Command Prompt" (VS2017 here) with the following log:

```
> checking pthread.h usability... no checking pthread.h presence... yes
> configure: WARNING: pthread.h: present but cannot be compiled
> configure: WARNING: pthread.h:     check for missing prerequisite
> headers? configure: WARNING: pthread.h: see the Autoconf documentation
> configure: WARNING: pthread.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be
> Compiled" configure: WARNING: pthread.h: proceeding with the
> compiler's result checking for pthread.h... no configure: error:
> pthread.h is missing Error 0 in ./configure
```

I think I miss some prerequisites or something. I've tried to install pthread manually from ftp://sourceware.org/pub/pthreads-win32/dll-latest (following some google links).
But is it the good link?

I've also seen some answers here like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33535025/how-to-compile-jemalloc-on-windows), but it does not work for me, maybe because referencing an older version of jemalloc.

How to install jemalloc properly on Windows?

Edit:
Tried to use Cygwin instead of bash, the error is now:

```
> configure: error: Unsupported intmax_t size: 0
```

Comment: pthreads is a header API for Unix threading, I wouldn't expect it to build on Windows. There is possibly something wrong in the config .sh scripts if it is checking for pthreads on windows.